# How do I mark a Question as solved on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support

I had asked a question on stackoverflow.com and now it's been answered. How do I mark the question as solved?

Comment: The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) shows how to accept an answer, i. e. to mark a question as solved.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234)

Comment: Just in case - please make sure to also read about difference between "answer" and "comment" (people mixing these two things a lot on SO). If you are talking about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62788357/specify-custom-icon-when-using-pyinstaller that question indeed have reasonable answer (and after some edit has good title as well no thank you notes in the answer).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Stack Overflow does not have "solved" system like other Q&A sites. Askers instead may "accept" an answer that they view is either correct or most helpful. This system allows future answers to be posted, whereas traditional "solved" systems prevent new answers from being posted.

Refer to what you should do when someone answers your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

I have noticed lots of folks say "Thank You" in comments. Please don't do that. Instead, hit the "Upvote" button.